# Simple Java console calculator- clean code

Tags: java, calculator

I am new to Java programming, but from the very beginning I want to write the clean code. I prepared the simple console calculator, but want to make it better. What could be changed to make code below more clear? How do you suggest to add try/ catch blocks and exceptions?

Main class:

```
import Calculator.Calculator;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator calculator= new Calculator();
    calculator.action();
  }
}
```

and the Calculator class:
    package Calculator;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
private int number1;
private int number2;
private int userActionChoice;

public void action() {
    displayMenu();
    getUserAction();
    getNumbers(number1, number2);
    executeUserAction(userActionChoice);
}

private void displayMenu() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to my calculator!\n");
    System.out.println("Please choose action: ");
    System.out.println("1. Add");
    System.out.println("2. Subtract");
    System.out.println("3. Multipy");
    System.out.println("4. Divide");
}

private int getUserAction() {
    Scanner gettingUserAction = new Scanner(System.in);
    userActionChoice = gettingUserAction.nextInt();
    return userActionChoice;
}

public void getNumbers(int num1, int num2) {
    System.out.println("Please enter first number: ");
    getNum1(num1);
    System.out.println("Please enter second number: ");
    getNum2(num2);
}

private void getNum1(int number1) {
    Scanner gettingNum1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    this.number1 = gettingNum1.nextInt();
}

private void getNum2(int number2) {
    Scanner gettingNum2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    this.number2 = gettingNum2.nextInt();
}

private void executeUserAction(int choice) {
    switch (choice) {
    case 1: {
        System.out.println(add());
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        System.out.println(subtract());
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        System.out.println(multiply());
        break;
    }
    case 4: {
        System.out.println(divide());
        break;
    }
    default: {
        System.out.println("Unknown command!");
    }
    }
}

private int add() {
    return number1 + number2;
}

private int subtract() {
    return number1 - number2;
}

private int multiply() {
    return number1 * number2;
}

private int divide() {
    if(number2 != 0) {
    return number1 / number2;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Cannot divide by 0!");
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Thank you for any piece of advice!

Comment: An obvious answer would be adding comments to your code.

Comment: the code is aligned correctly, efficient and variables/methods/classes have appropriate names. In terms of readability and clarity it looks great, just lacks proper commenting

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think it looks fine. If readability is good like in this case, additional comments are not needed. Use lowercase letters for package names. As pointed out, for future code reviews use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for all your comments and pieces of advice!

I am sorry for the off-topic - I did not know about codereview.stackexchange.com- thank you, I will use it in the future!

I think that topic can be closed.